# Change login table in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I started using Laravel recently and I ran the `artisan make:auth` to make a login and register.

The thing is, I want to use the a table I already had, that is called `partners` and not create a new one called `users`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your : `config/auth.php`

do this changes

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Partner::class, //put the right model name here  that will handle the login/registration or you can use database driver
        ],
    ],
```

Then in your **Partner model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Partner extends Model
    {
        /**
         * The table associated with the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'partners'; // specify table name

         //rest of the model
    }
```

This should be fine